# Module not found: Can't resolve 'regenerator-runtime' in next js 12.1.5 with react 18 with node 16

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js

My package.json is like

```
   "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.1.5",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  }
```

After starting dev, I am getting the below error.

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'D:\mywebsites\next.jsudemy\next-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js' in 'D:\mywebsites\next.js\udemy\next-blog\node_modules\next\dist\client\dev'
```

Comment: Try re-installing dependencies... `rm -r node_modules package-lock.json && npm i`

Answer (score 0):

As I have same issues, I have downgraded react@17.0.2
and react-dom@17.0.2

Now seems working.